Django application logs are not rotated
In a Django application, version 3.2.14, running on an ec2 instance that also has a gunicorn web server with 9 workers, plus ngnix and with the log configuration shown below, the files are not rotated.
The user of the gunicorn service is ubuntu and belongs to the group: www-data
What could it be? Is there an issue with gunicorn and the workers?
I appreciate your answers.
LOGGING = {
    "version": 1,
    "disable_existing_loggers": False,
    "formatters": {
        "simple": {"format": "%(levelname)s %(message)s"},
        "verbose": {
            "format": "[%(levelname)8s] [%(asctime)s] [%(funcName)30s] %(message)s"
        },
        "elegant": {
            "format": (
                "%(asctime)s [%(levelname)-8s] " "(%(module)s.%(funcName)s) %(message)s"
            ),
            "datefmt": "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S",
        },
    },
    "handlers": {
        "console": {
            "level": "INFO",
            "class": "logging.StreamHandler",
            "formatter": "elegant",
        },
        "app": {
            "level": "INFO",
            "class": "logging.handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler",
            "formatter": "elegant",
            "filename": os.path.join("logs", "app"),
            "when": "D",
            "interval": 30,
            "encoding": "utf-8",
        },
        "groups": {
            "level": "INFO",
            "class": "logging.handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler",
            "formatter": "elegant",
            "filename": os.path.join("logs", "groups"),
            "when": "D",
            "interval": 30,
            "encoding": "utf-8",
        },
    },
    "root": {
        "level": "INFO",
        "handlers": ["console"],
        "formatter": "elegant",
    },
    "loggers": {
        "app": {
            "level": "INFO",
            "handlers": ["app"],
            "propagate": True,
        },
        "groups": {
            "level": "INFO",
            "handlers": ["groups"],
            "propagate": True,
        },
    },
}


This is because gunicorn is logging using 2 or more processes.
If you want to rotate the log file, it is easier to create a separate code to manage the log file.

This answer and this link helped me find the solution to the problem.
